# Parsing CSV file (Python)

Tags: python, csv, python-2.x

I have a CSV file with the following format:

```
"SHA-1","MD5","CRC32","FileName","FileSize","ProductCode","OpSystemCode"
```

Basically what I'm looking to do in Python 2.x is read the file and if within the filename column, any files exist with a specified file extension from a list, the data from the MD5 hash column is parsed out into a text document.

So my pseudo code is looking like this:

```
list = [.doc,.xls,.ppt]

with open(new.csv) as new_f:
    with open(x.csv) as old_f:
        x = f.readlines()
        if list in x:
            # *copy out the value from the MD5 value column to new.csv*
```

I just don't know how to extract the MD5 hash.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us your *real* code instead of your *pseudo* code?

Comment: [The `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

Comment: That was my real code other than the final line

Comment: @thefragileomen: it isn't. this won't even pass syntax check.

Answer (score 0):

Create one list for the MD5-Hash and one for the filename, if the list is in the item of the filename list, save the index and use it for your MD5 list (since you've got a table the index has to be the same)

Comment: So maybe split the file into two, one containing filenames and one containing MD5 and then bring both into respective lists and if filename[200] contains .doc for example, then copy out md5[200] into a new txt file?

Comment: Yes, I think this would be a possible solution for you. You can also use the other information (SHA-1,...) with the saved index!

Answer (score 0):

Solution identified:-

```
import csv

results = []
filetypes = ['jpg','bmp','jpeg','mov','mp4','avi','wmv','wav','tif','gif','png']
reader = csv.reader(open('c:\users\me\Desktop\x.csv'))
for extension in filetypes:
    for line in reader:  # iterate over the lines in the csv
        if extension in line[3]:
            print line[1] + "\t" + line[3]
```